# How does our community want to handle quality comments posted as answers that are too long for a comment?

Tags: discussion

In [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/81282/open-source-software-for-noise-modelling-gis-as-an-alternative-to-soundplan/81284), our new community member (welcome Marco_B!) posted a **high quality** comment as an answer.  The comment is too long to be a single comment, so we have a few choices on how to handle these types of occurrences.

Please upvote below the answer that matches your preference.  If none of the current answers match your preference, please add another answer.

Comment: Just thinking out aloud: on our sister sites, an answer pointing out why there cannot be an answer is still counted as valid answer. So while being borderline: as long as there's no answer proving otherwise, wouldn't the same count here?

Comment: @Izzy If there truly *cannot* be an answer (e.g. an OS does not support the required functionality), I'm all in favour of answers pointing out such a situation.

Answer (score 4):

Leave the high quality comment as an answer.  This preserves the formatting (including paragraphs) and allows others to more easily comment on what is presented in the answer.  It also allows the author and others to edit the content (as opposed to a comment, in which even the original author cannot perform an edit after 5 minutes).

Answer (score 2):

Ask the post's author to please copy and paste their answer as multiple comments on the question.

If they do not have enough reputation to post comments, flag the answer for a moderator to perform those steps (note that, as moderators, we can only make the first comment *- limited to 600 characters -* appear as if written by the original author; additional comments required for the remainder of the original post will appear to be from the moderator).